# More optimized way to do itertools.combinations

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I'm trying to find unique combinations of ~70,000 IDs.
I'm currently doing an `itertools.combinations([list name], 2)` to get unique 2 ID combinations but it's been running for more than 800 minutes.
Is there a faster way to do this?

I tried converting the IDs into a matrix where the IDs are both the index and the columns and populating the matrix using `itertools.product`.

I tried doing it the manual way with loops too.
But after more than a full day of letting them run, none of my methods have actually finished running.

For additional information, I'm storing these into a data frame, to later run a function that compares each of the unique set of IDs.

Comment: It would help us to help you if you post your code

Comment: You are trying to process about 2.45 billion combinations. It's going to take a while, and if you're trying to hold them all in memory at once (like with that matrix), it may take more memory than you have.

Answer (score 1):

(70_000 ** 69_000) / 2== 2.4 billion - it is not such a large number as to be not computable in a few hours (*update* I run a dry-run on `itertools.product(range(70000), 2)` and it took less than 70 seconds, on a 2017 era i7 @3GHz, naively using a single core) But if you are trying to keep this data in memory at once, them it won't fit - and if your system is configured to swap memory to disk before erroring with a MemoryError, this may slow-down the program by  2 or more orders of magnitude, and thus, that is when your problem come from.

`itertools.combination` does the right thing in this respect, and no need to try to change it for something else: it will yield one combination at a time. What you are *doing* with the result, however, do change things: if you are streaming the combination to a file and not keeping it in memory, it should be fine, and then, it is just computational time you can't speed up anyway.

If, on the other hand, you are collecting the combinations to a list or other data structure: there is your problem - don't do it.

Now. going a step further than your question, since these combinations are check-able and predictable, maybe trying to generate these is not the right approach at all - you don't give details on how these are to be used, but if used in a reactive form, or on a lazy form, you might have an instantaneous workflow instead.

Comment: Yes - I mistook it with something that would allow repetition of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ram will run full. You can counter this with gc.collect() or emtpying the results but the found results have to be saved inbetween.
You could try something similar to the code below. I would create individual file names or save the results into a database since the result file will be some gb big. Additionaly range of the second loop can probably be divided by 2.

```
import gc
new_set=set()

for i in range(70000):
    new_set.add(i)

print(new_set)

combined_set=set()

for i in range(len(new_set)):
    print(i)
    if i % 300 ==0:
        with open("results","a") as f:
            f.write(str(combined_set))
        combined_set=set()
        gc.collect()
    for b in range(len(new_set)):
        combined_set.add((i,b))
```

Comment: There is no need to manually call the GC if the code is designed not to keep references to generated values. Just rewriting the previous set with the `combined_set=set()` statement is enough: it will trigger the synchronous deletion of the previous instance as its references go to 0, in standard cPython.